# Creating step functions to converge to continuous functions.

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I have for example $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ both with domains on $[0,1]$. How do I make step functions $g_n(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ that converge to $g(x)$ and $f(x)$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty}g_n(x)=g(x) \ \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$

In this example, and how is it done in general?

Comment: I mean step-functions, I have to edit all this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a general method :

---

We define a family of partitions of $[0,1]$ :

$$I_{n,m}=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\left[ \frac m {2^{n}},\frac {m+1} {2^{n}}  \right) & \text{ if }& 0\leq m < 2^n-1\\ 
\left[ \frac m {2^{n}},\frac {m+1} {2^{n}}  \right] & \text{ if }& m = 2^n-1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \cup_{0\leq m < 2^n} I_{n,m}=[0,1] \text{ and } I_{n,m_1} \cap I_{n,m_2} = \emptyset \text{ if } m_1 \neq m_2.$$

Now, define the sequence :
$$h_n(x)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{2^n-1} \chi_{I_{n,m}}(x) h\left(\frac m {2^n}\right)$$

With $\chi_A$ the indicator function of the set $A$.

---

Now, with all this defined, we claim the following :

> For every continuous function $h$ on $[0,1]$, $h_n$ converges pointwise to
>   $h$.

**Proof :**

Let $x \in [0,1)$ : $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists ! m, 0\leq m < 2^n, x\in I_{n,m}$$

$x \in I_{n,m} \Rightarrow x \in \left[ \frac m {2^{n}},\frac {m+1} {2^{n}}  \right) \Rightarrow 2^n x \in \left[ m , m+1 \right)$

Then $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x\in I_{n,m} \Rightarrow m= \lfloor x 2^n \rfloor.$$

With $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ the floor function. So by the definition of $h_n$ : $$h_n(x)=h\left(\lfloor x 2^n \rfloor \frac 1 {2^n} \right)=h\left( (x2^n-\lbrace x2^n\rbrace) \frac 1 {2^n} \right) \to h(x)$$
With $\lbrace\cdot \rbrace$ the fractionnal part function.

If $x=1$, $\forall n, x \in I_{n,2^n-1}$.

$h_n(1)=h\left( \frac {2^n-1} {2^n}\right)=h\left( 1- \frac {1} {2^n}\right) \to h(1)$.

---

Some remarks :

1. If $h$ admits a discontinuity, the claim may be wrong,
2. The general method can be quite easily extended to any compact and connected set,
3. The major difficulty of that proof is in the notations.

Comment: This is very detailed. I greatly appreciate the effort. I will look into it in more detail a couple of days. Thank you.